# ERROR: Network is unreachable (connect failed)

Tags: android-studio, gradle

i want to start learning android studio, but when i created my first project, there is this error and i can't find any solution that can solve my problem, please help me.

the error is : ERROR: Network is unreachable (connect failed)

and here is a screenshot of my Android Studio :
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/134bn.png)

And I am running android studio on ubuntu 18.04.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet is required for gradle.

Check your PC connectivity and be sure network access is enabled for Android studio in your firewall.

Comment: Ah you are right, it was the firewall, i didn't know that Ubuntu has firewall until now, thank you kind sir. But does that mean i should disable firewall everytime i want to use Android Studio ?